# ICACLS Folder and subfolders

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to create a batch script that will deny writing, in the folder test and the subfolders, for the SYSTEM user, Administrator user and Administrators group ( like when you chose the option deny write, right click> security).

After that I need to put it back to normal like before just normal.

I tried this:

```
icacls C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test /deny SYSTEM:W
icacls C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test /deny Administrator:W
icacls C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test /deny Administrators:W
```

and to undo I'm doing

```
icacls C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test /grant :r System:W
icacls C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test /grant :r Administrator:W
icacls C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test /grant :r Administrators:W
```

but I'm not able to write in that folder, to make a new file after doing this.

Comment: Assuming that this script will be running from either System or Administrator(s) - I would guess that when you run the deny command you are removing their permissions to write to that directory and they therefore cannot change the permissions on that directory. Why do you want to change the permissions for those users, then change them back?

Comment: because there is an exploit in that application and if I want to add something I will need to disable deny write put the things there and put again to deny.

Answer (score -1):

I created an icacls dos command to run in the logon batch file for users, either through Group Policy Logon Script or through the domain profile logon.bat file.

```
icacls c:\users\%username%\Desktop /deny :W
```

This denies write access to the specific user. It can be modified for your particular use. Just use icacls /? for further switches. The switches have to be preceded with a colon (:) as shown in the example.